# Linux: How to allow outbound rules for seccurity updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, security-groups

We use aws ec2 instances with the 'AWS Linux AMI 2' image.

We have a script for security updates with this code: `yum update -y --security`.

I want to allow only security update in outbound rules - aws security group.
Can someone tell me what is the port + ip? if it has a specific IP...
I think the port is HTTP 80 since it works after I add it.

Comment: It's not possible(it think is complecate) you need know every domain or possible domain, but you can secure command using sudo for example to protect unauthorized user execute the yum command.

Comment: I talked about the security group (I will have to open the instanse with rule 80 to everyone!), the script itself is avaiable only with SUDO.

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS recommendations, you should allow outbound HTTP & HTTPS traffic to the internet from the security group attached to the EC2 instance, in order to allow security updates.

REFERENCE: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html#:~:text=DBServerSG%20security%20group.-,0.0.0.0/0,Allow%20outbound%20HTTPS%20access%20to%20any%20IPv4%20address.,-The%20following%20table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html#:%7E:text=DBServerSG%20security%20group.-,0.0.0.0/0,Allow%20outbound%20HTTPS%20access%20to%20any%20IPv4%20address.,-The%20following%20table)

[AWS Security Group - Outbound Rule recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0MpT.png)